# How to get yyyy-mm-dd from mm/dd/yyy in Excel

Tags: excel, vba, date, format

I have a date in mm/dd/yyyy format from a textbox in a userform, and I want to get each value mm, dd, and yyyy to a number. (Example, 10/12/2020 would become 2020-10-12)

Here is my code so far, which gets the month part finished.

```
Dim DateDay As String, DateMonth As String, DateYear As String
Dim firstslash As Integer, secondslash As Integer
firstslash = InStr(TextBox3, "/")
DateMonth = Left(TextBox3, firstslash - 1)
If Len(DateMonth) = 1 Then
DateMonth = "0" & DateMonth
End If

'code for day and year

MsgBox("Date =" & DateYear & "-" & DateMonth & "-" & DateDay)
```

How can I add to this so it can get the day and year part as well?

Comment: Just use `Format$` here.

Comment: @BigBen could you provide how this would look like implemented into code? Thanks. I am unfamiliar with Format$

Comment: The [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/format-function-visual-basic-for-applications) should be helpful. Well they are for `Format` but the usage is the same.

Comment: @BigBen , thanks! I used Format(UserForm1.TextBox3.Value, "yyyy-mm-dd") and it works now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trick is to be sure that you are dealing with a **date**, that is a large integer (43861 for today). Therefore you should convert whatever is in the textbox to an integer representing a date. That *true* date you can then present in any format you want. The code below does exactly that.

```
Private Sub CallExtractDate()

    Dim Dat As Date

    Dat = ExtractDate("01/31/2020")
    MsgBox Format(Dat, "yyyy-mm-dd") & vbCr & _
           Format(Dat, "ddd, dd mmm, yyyy") & vbCr & _
           Format(Dat, "dddd")
End Sub

Function ExtractDate(ByVal TxtDate As String) As Date

    Dim Sp() As String

    If IsDate(TxtDate) Then
        ExtractDate = CDate(TxtDate)
    Else
        Sp = Split(TxtDate, "/")
        On Error Resume Next
        ExtractDate = DateSerial(Int(Sp(2)), Int(Sp(0)), Int(Sp(1)))
    End If
End Function
```

In your project you would probably use the function with a call like this.

```
Dat = ExtractDate(TextBox1.Value)
```